# Bit conversion not working in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bit, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I'm working on `SSRS` report. I have `Dataset` that returns below values.

[image]

Now I wanted to change color of `Data` field on bases of this `bit`.

I tried below, but no success. It always shows `False` in report.

```
=IIF(CBool(Fields!IsAuthorized.Value)=True,"Blue","Black")
=IIF(CInt(Fields!IsAuthorized.Value)=1,"Blue","Black")
=IIF(Fields!IsAuthorized.Value=1,"Blue","Black")
```

Below Image show `IsAuthorized.Value` on data field.

[image]

Please help me!

Comment: Simply `Fields!IsAuthorized.Value = True` should work fine, as should `Fields!IsAuthorized.Value <> 0` as Leptonator suggests below. But several of the things you tried already should have worked too. What's strange to me is that you're seeing `False` for all three values when displaying IsAuthorized.Value on the report. When you run the dataset query from the "Data" tab in SSRS designer, do you see True, False, True as expected there?

Comment: yes while running in Report builder it shows perfect. 1 0 1 but not in web page. tried to check in all browsers It's really strange issue I found ever in SSRS work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable time. :) @Benjamin

Comment: Wait, so does it behave normally even in "Preview" mode in report builder? Is it only getting strange once you deploy it to your server?

Maybe you could show us the query your dataset is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with while I was passing the value to `Dataset` to fetch rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Number,
       [dbo].[Function](@UserID) AS IsAuthorized,
FROM   TableName
```

Here, `@UserID` always passed as blank from my web application and this is why conversion gets failed.

I changed my below line of code in web app to set it's correct value.

**Before**

```
ReportParams.Add(new ReportParameter("UserId", Request.QueryString["UserId"].ToString()));
```

**After**

```
ReportParams.Add(new ReportParameter("UserID", Request.QueryString["UserID"].ToString()));
```

Also, I have set `Default values` for `@UserID` in Parameters properties as blank. This is why also it was causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here..

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1459800-1063-1.aspx

For example:

```
=IIF( Fields!IsState.Value <> 0 and Fields!RegionID.Value <>"12","Yes","No")
```

So yours should be something like:

```
=IIF( Fields!IsAuthorized.Value <> 0 ,Black,Blue)
```

This should cover it.

Comment: Thank you so much... but I already checked your suggested link before. the issue was totally different. Again thanks.